# How to make a child theme after style.css has been customized

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a theme that has already been customized. Only one file in the theme has been customized, that file is the style.css. A child theme was NOT created before doing the customizations.

I would like to make a child theme so the customizations are not lost when the theme is upgraded. How do I add the customizations in the style.css to new child theme?

Thank you.

Comment: Just edit the information at the top of style.css so it becomes a new theme.

Comment: There is absolutely no way of doing this easy. You will need to get a copy of the original theme, and then work side by side with your customized theme and try to work out what was changed and then these changes needs to be moved into a child theme. Unfortunately you will need a lot of time and patience here. I hope people that makes customizations to themes they did not write, see this, and understand why we always say, never ever do this

Comment: Thank you, of course, always make the child theme BEFORE customizing. So I am using comparemyfiles.com to compare the original to the customized version. This highlights the lines that are different. Put my customized css into dreamweaver so I can see the code line number. Copy and paste the lines that are different from start of the phrase and end of the curly brackets, ready to go in child. Works well unless you have pasted in extra lines. Then you have to remove the extra lines so the program can tell you which lines are different. Job is much faster with a code comparing tool.

Answer (score 0):

you should check your all files and folders of theme . sometime your theme has a dynamic css file like sass, less or other ....  if you have a dynamic css file, you should customize that file ....
if you haven't dynamic css files, you can customize your main css file as you want.